# MASM32 CreateFile

Tags: assembly, masm

I am trying to open file via CreateFile in MASM32, but I am getting INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE when opening a legit file.

```
.386 
.model flat,stdcall 
option casemap:none 
include \masm32\include\windows.inc 
include \masm32\include\user32.inc 
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

.DATA
FileName db "C:\Users\machine\Desktop\putty.exe",NULL
BadText db "Its not ok",0
OkText db "Its ok",0
.DATA?
hFile HANDLE ?

.CODE
start: 
    invoke CreateFile,addr FileName,GENERIC_READ OR GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_READ OR FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL
    mov hFile,eax
    cmp hFile, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
    jz code1
    invoke MessageBox,NULL,addr OkText,addr OkText,MB_OK
    invoke ExitProcess,0



code1:
    invoke MessageBox,NULL,addr BadText,addr BadText,MB_OK
    invoke ExitProcess,0
    ret

end start
```

I tried \ instead of \, NULL instead of 0 but nothing worked. Thanks for help.

Comment: There are two functions, CreateFileA() which uses legacy 8-bit string encoding and CreateFileW() which uses Unicode strings.  Hard to guess what these .inc files do with "CreateFile", I can guess.  Use CreateFileA.   You don't know why it doesn't work because you didn't write the code to find out why the function failed.  Using GetLastError() is not something you should ever omit, even in assembly.  Well, especially in assembly.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code, it works. The problem must be with the target file. Whether it is a permissions problem or something else, I don't know.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
invoke CreateFile, addr FileName, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE or FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL
```